# React Navigation Switch Navigator not working after importing class from another file

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Hi Please see my code Here :

https://snack.expo.io/@ersimransingh/navigation-problem

I have created my switch navigator to navigate between pages from App.js to Second.js

On App.js page I have imported Second.js file module named App1 Which works file.

Moreover, I did the same thing on Second.js file imported App component from App.js But swith navigator show error on the page says

The component for route 'App' must be a React component.

I did search on internet for the same, and tried replacing my imporing syntax from 
import {App} from './App';
to 
import App from './App';

You can Check my code on expo
https://snack.expo.io/@ersimransingh/navigation-problem

Answer (score 0):

You have App.js which is creating a route using Second.js and Second.js is creating a route using App.js. This is definitely problematic, because you are creating a cicular reference. Rather, you should create your navigation in one place and use it in the App.js

Here is an example:
App.js

```
  export default class App extends React.Component{
      render(){
        return(
          <CreateTag />
        );
      }
    }

const AppContainer = createSwitchNavigator({
  FirstScreen,
  SecondScreen 
});

const CreateTag = createAppContainer(AppContainer);
```

FirstScreen.js

```
    export default class FirstScreen extends React.Component {
      render() {
        let { navigation } = this.props;

        return (
          <View>
            <Text
              style={styles.sampleText}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SecondScreen')}>
              First screen
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

SecondScreen.js

```
export default class SecondScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let { navigation } = this.props;

    return (
      <View>
        <Text
          style={styles.sampleText}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('FirstScreen')}>
          Second screen
        </Text> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the complete example: https://snack.expo.io/S1cY9IVEV
Also you can check from the official example: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/App.js

I hope this helps.